# Multiple RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to have multiple RewriteRules in my .htaccess file.

```
# Enable Rewriting
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite profile urls
# Input: /user<userId>
# Output: /profile.php?id=<userId>
RewriteRule ^user(\d+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]

# Rewrite by default to redirect.php
RewriteRule .* redirect.php
```

Every requests points to redirect.php

I thought, with the [L] flag in the first RewriteRule, would stop processing the rule set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to the second RewriteRule works.

```
# Rewrite by default to redirect.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* redirect.php
```

But im not sure, why this is needed.

Comment: **1st:** If the requested filename is not a regular file, continue the rule execution. **2nd:** If the requested filename is not a directory, continue the rule execution.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to rewrite `/user<userId>` to `/profile.php?id=<userId>` and rewrite the other URLs to */redirect.php*, then you could try these two configuration directives:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^user([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule .* /redirect.php
```

OR:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^user([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /redirect.php
```

Answer (score 0):

[L] flag stops processing only in current iteration but mod_rewrite repeat process until path will not be constant.
In your case I think you can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^user\d+$ profile.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !profile.php
RewriteRule ^.*$ redirect.php
```